# Payment Gateway with Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am building an Ionic 2 app, and want to integrate a payment gateway.

Requirements:
- needs to be able to send and receive payments to/from major credit and debit cards and PayPal.

Much like how Uber allows payments to be sent and received.

Please can anyone advise what good plugins are available.

Thanks

Comment: Best way to have some payment gateway, like stripe.

Comment: Thanks.  I see they charge 2.9% + 30c per transaction.  Is that competitive?

Comment: That depends on your business model. Try google for alternative payment gateways and choose what you prefer

Comment: did you tried this option, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-applepay

Answer (score 0):

You can use these ionic 2 native plugin to do that

[Plugin 1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/) or  [Plugin 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe/)

But I think the better way to do that you can write NodeJS api to process payment.
this is the package you can use node-payments

> Node-payments is a express based facade to multiple payment services

The idea is an simple and inutive API to handle just simple single payments. It's als designed to add more payment services over time, but without changing the general API.